# Ruby on Rails - write all 500 errors to log file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to write all 500 errors (and their backtraces) on my site to a separate log file than my development.log or production.log file. How can this be achieved?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you can create your custom log file using

```
Logger.new("#{Rails.root}/log/my.log")
```

and write 500 errors in this custom log file

Answer (score 0):

You can try the exception handling in the controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  rescue_from Exception, :with => :log_exception

  def log_exception(exception)
    File.open(Rails.root.join('logs', 'errors.log'), 'a+') do |f|
      f.write(exception.stacktrace)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I just tested this and it's essentially the functionality that I need. However, when a error is thrown, this is preventing Rails from handling errors like it normally does (redirecting to a 500 page, etc).